# Create function/variable/parameter in pgAdmin with specific values

Tags: postgresql, variables, parameters

Not sure whether this is possible and what's the best way to do it, but I have a list of values (say it is 'ACBC', 'ADFC', 'AGGD' etc.) which grows over time. I want to use these values in **pgADmin** as a sort of variable/parameter for SQL statements; e.g:

Codes = {'ACBC', 'ADFC', 'AGGD'}

SQL: Statement => `SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE SUBSTRING IN (Codes)`

Is that somehow realizable, either with a variable, parameter, function or anyhing else?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following options:

1) Create separate table

```
create table qry_params(prm_value varchar);
insert into qry_params values
  ('xxx'),
  ('yyy'),
  ('zzz');

select * from xxx where substring in (select prm_value from qry_params)
```

Whenever you have new parameter, you just need to add it to the table.

2) CTE at the top of query

Use query like:

```
with params (prm_value) as (select values ('xxx'), ('yyy'), ('zzz'))
select * from xxx where substring in (select prm_value from qry_params)
```

Whenever you have new parameter, you just need to add it to the CTE.